# Sorting in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am creating a NSTableView & using the delegate & datasource link to the class I am flooding the table. In the class i am using the NSMutableArray to store the values for the table. can I do sorting in the table. How can I do that. I want to sort as per the values in the column.
I am using the sort hey & selector but when I run I am getting this error 
 `[<NSCFString 0x18da00> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.`

how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this in one of two ways. The easier way, that's not as prone to failure if you aren't sure what you're doing, is to simply sort your content array. You can use `NSMutableArray`'s `-sort...:` methods to sort it, and the results will appear sorted in the table.

However, the 'better' way is to have the table sort output on its own, using an `NSSortDescriptor` (you can either set this in code, or through Interface Builder). To get a sort descriptor to work with custom classes, you'd have to make them KVC-compliant, but luckily, you're only working with `NSString`s, so the work is already done for you. Either in Interface Builder, or in code, set the sort descriptor's key to `self` (since you're comparing the strings themselves, and not their instance variables) and the selector to `compare:` (since you just need to do a simple comparison, and `NSString`s implement this method). That's easily done in Interface Builder (once you set `self` as the key, `compare:` will even pop up for you), though if you'd have wanted to make a complex sort descriptor, you'd have had to make it in code.

Comment: thanks but I am using one column as NSString & other is a int. using self I am able to sort that but the other column is not working.

Comment: Are they related to each other? Are the individual rows important, or do they just need to be ordered from least to greatest? If they just need to be ordered, that's not difficult to do, but if the rows themselves are related, you're going to have to do some more difficult work.

Comment: thanks for the help...yes they are related. But I found one solution by sorting my NSMutableArray I am using.

Comment: Good. Glad I was able to help in some capacity.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the values in your table are `NSStrings`.  You need to select something that `NSString` responds to as the key.  Probably the key `self` will do the trick.